# how to append two mutable lists in ocaml

Tags: ocaml, mutable, refs

```ml
type 'a mylist = 'a listcell ref
and 'a listcell = Nil | Cons of 'a * ('a mylist)

let l1 = (ref (Cons (1, ref (Cons (2,ref Nil)))))
let l2 = (ref (Cons(3, ref (Cons(4, ref Nil)))))

let rec append l1 l2 =
match l1 with
 | {contents = Nil} -> (l1 := !l2; l1)
 | {contents = Cons(h,t)} -> append t l2
```

this is what i've got so far, the goal is to append l2 to l1
i can traverse to the end of l1 and replace the ref with l2... which
is what i was trying to do. but for some reason i lose everything that
came before that.

any help would be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you reach the end of the list through recursive calls, `l1` refers to the `Nil` element of the first list, not the beginning of the first list.

You can fix this by using a helper function inside `append` that works like your current `append` function. But at the end it returns the original `l1` from the outer `append` function.